# Stop an @HTML.Action from firing on pageload

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc

in my View, I have a `@HTML.Action` that is always fired on page load

```
<table style="margin:0 auto;margin-top:-10px;margin-bottom:20px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.Action("Search", new
            {
               id = @ViewData["id"]
            })
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

However, I dont want this action to be fired until I press a "Search" button..

I have a `Html.beginform` that will do a post - this is when I want the `@Html.Action` to be fired.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Search", FormMethod.Post))
{
 // a submit button and the @Html.Action are in here. So I am surprised the @HTML.Action is fired on load
}
```

Part of the Action event - *Note: the partial returns a List that is binded to a DevExpress GridView object*

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Search(string Ids)
{
     return PartialView("Search", My List<T> Object);
}
```

But I guess the code I need is on the View end?

Cheers

Comment: `Html.Action` calls the specified action and renders the output to the view, so you are describing expected behaviour. What exactly do you expect it to do instead? If you want a `<a>` tag then use `Html.ActionLink`

Comment: Well, on first load, the user wouldn't have any inputs for the Search method to process + get results, so I feel its pointless to even fire it, so the best way I guess it to return an empty partial result on pageload

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By HttpMethod you can check whether the page has been posted back or not. So whenever the Http method is POST then show the search.

```
<table style="margin:0 auto;margin-top:-10px;margin-bottom:20px;">
<tr>
    <td>
        @if(Request.HttpMethod.Equals("POST",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            @Html.Action("Search", new
            {
               id = @ViewData["id"]
            })
        }
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: This is not a very pleasant solution - seems almost like trying to shoehorn web forms convention into MVC. Not to mention that search forms should really be using GET requests, not POST.

Comment: Totally agree with the GET comment, but for me GETS in the URL query string look awful - but your theory is correct.